# Legit way to store a destructor information to a void*

Tags: c++

Is it legit to store the delete information of a void pointer in a function pointer like this?

```
typedef void(*deleter)(void*);
template <class T> void deleteVoidPointer(void* target)
{
    delete static_cast<T*>(target);
}

int main()
{
    void* p = new int;
    deleter del = deleteVoidPointer<int>;

    del(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any side effects I am missing here or is this a legit way to keep track of destructor information for a pointer? (Besides the missing check if target is a nullptr in deleteVoidPointer)

Comment: *"the missing check if target is a nullptr in deleteVoidPointer"*. deleting null pointer is valid as no-op.

Comment: What is the purpose of this unexpected construct ? The operator `delete` expects a `void*` so that it will undo your static cast, and though you will get different `deleter` addresses for different `T`, they are completely interchangeable. `deleteVoidPointer<bool>(p);` will work as well. You aren't storing any type information.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If I'm not mistaken, this will not be the case when working with polymorphic classes where destructors must be called. Deleting through a void* there might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: I am storing the typeinfo in the deleter pointer. the idea is to have a non template pointer deleter which points to a template function which will delete the void* correctly. Yes, delete would free the void* (but I am not even sure of this) if you leave it as void*, the destructor on the other hand wouldn't be called if you delete a pointer of regular type void. so basically you can init the deleter with the right type and then you can safe delete the void pointer in another function where you wouldn't know the type anymore.

Comment: @Mango: right, this will work as the correct destructor will be called. But it is your responsibility to keep track of the data type to invoke the correct `deleter`. Isn't it simpler/safer to keep typed pointers and cast them to void where required ? (or alias them)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not where I want to use this. I want to use this for some type ereasure attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code you've shown is perfectly valid.

And there's no missing check: calling `delete` on a null pointer is guaranteed to do nothing.